# Error during Rendering of region "DROPZONE_UPLOAD" in oracle apex

Tags: oracle-apex

I have recently installed my working APEX application from development environment to test environment. I have a plugin "Dropzone 2 [Plug-In]" in my application, and I have created a region "DROPZONE_UPLOAD", of type 'Interactive Report'. Once the attachements are attached using Plugin "Dropzone 2", the results are displayed under "DROPZONE UPLOAD" region.

In my DEV environment the application with this plugin was working fine without any issues. But now I have exported and imported the same complete application in other environment. And when I try to run the application it gives me this error : "Error during rendering of region DROPZONE_UPLOAD " . Can you please help.

Regards,
Abha

Comment: Did you install the plugin in the test Apex environment as well?

Comment: Place the page in debug mode, and/or run with Page Designer logged into the same browser - you should get more detail. Also check browser console for errors.

Comment: @Littlefoot : I have imported the whole application and installed it. The application already had the plugin, so do I need to install plugin explicitly again. I can see the plugin in the application that i have imported in test environment.

Comment: @Scott : I am trying to get the developer toolbar on the page for debugging , but I am not able to get the developer toolbar. Is it because, I am coming to APEX page via EBS SSo login.

Comment: You should be able to manipulate the DEBUG parameter manually, to at least turn debugging on. I wouldn't think SSO would impact the toolbar. Check a page without an error.

Comment: @Scott : Hi, could see the debug message under application --> utilities -- > debug messages. There I was able to see the error message . It says : "PLS-00201: identifier 'XXUA_APEX_ATTACHMENT_PKG.GET_CATEGORIES' must be declared ORA-06550: line 6, column 1: PL/SQL: Statement ignored 4 " .But actually it exists on this environment too. I tried to hide the column which makes use of this call. After that I am getting the APEX page, but my plugin is missing from that. I kind of get a blank page. Can you please suggest why this is happening. It looks like the plugin import doesnt work on Test env.

Comment: I have also tried to create a fresh application in Development env. with just the plugin. It again works fine on Dev, but when I exported and imported the file on Test env. , again the plugin functionality doesnt appear on screen. Though Plugin information is there on the application builder after the import. Please help.

Comment: Where is the supporting PL/SQL? Sounds like no longer within plugin, which is good, but if compiled as package - don't forget to move that, too!